# Ubuntu 16.04 missing interface parts

Tags: unity

I was installing Python 3.5 and openCV on my Ubuntu notebook. Suddenly the Chrome windows closed and I noticed that many applications disappeared like Chrome it self and Firefox. Then I restarted the machine and I logged again. The top bar was missing, the lateral menu was missing, the top bar of the file manager window have no superior menu. The only thing I can see is some icons and the wallpaper.

I'also tried to press Ctrl+Alt+T and nothing happens.

I've entered in recovery mode and created a new user. So I rebooted but I couldn't login. When I insert my password and press enter, it goes back to the login screen as nothing happened. My last try was login as guest user but it only show the wallpaper.

Sorry for my poor english and for my crying but I'm really upset with this. It is the worst moment possible.

Comment: One reason you can not login (using gui) is you are out of disk space; so check for that. Switch to terminal (ctrl+alt+f4), login and enter `df -hi` (disk free; -h (human) & -i (inodes) mostly as its learnt by my fingers).  The commands you used for installing/adding python 3.5 & openCV would also be useful (whilst logged in at terminal, you can use `history` to view your command history to refresh your memory). The closing windows sounds more like `kill`...

Comment: No my disk have 57% free.

Comment: For installing openCV i've run a git clone, then installed cmake, build-essential and pkg-config. Then 'cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local'. I've rebooted before finishing the installation. I didn't get what you said about kill.

Comment: I've installed Cinnamon what I prefer. I think I got what you said about kill. But chrome and Firefox vanished from my computer, also Software Center.

Comment: Which method of "Installing Python 3.5" were you doing? There are several. The wrong method will immediately break your system quite horribly, as essential system components depend upon a specific version of Python.

Comment: Well I just did "apt-get install python3". But I'm really sure that You are right. Something have broke any interface dependency. I would like to really sove this because it could help someone. I have already seen a server with part of this symptoms so I'm really interested in the solution. But now I have a dead line to worry and then I will solve this and come back to answer this.